# Laravel remove parent if related collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model with a related collection

now im doing this query

```
        $data = DeliveryPartner::when($filter, function ($q) use ($request) {
        })
        ->with(['orders' => function ($query) {
            $query
                  ->where('delivery_partner_invoice_id', '=', '')
                  ->orWhereNull('delivery_partner_invoice_id')
                  ->whereIn('status', ['payment-accepted', 'completed', 'full-refund', 'partial-refund']);
        }])->get();
```

Now i am wondering. If the orders returns empty is it posible to remove this parent from the collection?

I Know i can do this after the eloquent query with a loop. But is it possible to do this in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant completely remove that parent ( with index ) BUT you can set those to `null` using [transform()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) like this;

```
    $data = DeliveryPartner::when($filter, function ($q) use ($request) {
        })
        ->with(['orders' => function ($query) {
            $query
                  ->where('delivery_partner_invoice_id', '=', '')
                  ->orWhereNull('delivery_partner_invoice_id')
                  ->whereIn('status', ['payment-accepted', 'completed', 'full-refund', 'partial-refund']);
        }])->get()->transform(function($item){

                if(!$item->orders->count() ){
                    return;
                }
                return $item;
        });
```

Note: this will not completely remove those parents but it will set them to empty.

Comment: You can chain these also `->filter()->values()` to filter the null value then returns a new collection with the keys reset